# Given a set S and a number k, get all the maximal subset satisfying the sum of them <=k?

Tags: algorithm, subset, np-hard

PS:
Output doesn't contain any set which is a subset of other.
1)`If X = {1, 2, 3}` is one of the solution then all the subsets of `X {1} {2} {3} {1, 2} {1, 3} {2, 3}` are omitted.

I know there are some algorithms to solve it.But I wonder whether there is a polynomial algorithm. If one exist, how does it work? If not, how to prove it as a NP-hard problem.

Thanks!

Comment: It's clearly NP via reduction from subset sum. (Since you generate all subsets, just find the subset that has sum equal to the target)

Comment: @nneonneo was thinking the same but still thinking the details of the reduction, but yea I think it is NP-hard using subset sum reduction

Comment: Thanks for your help